# СИ Во всем тексте после каждых трех слов вставить слово "блин"

Tags: c

Дана программа по заданию: **"Во всем тексте после каждых трех слов вставить слово "блин"**". У меня вышло только вставить слово блин один раз, а должно по всему тексту через 3 слова, дальше не знаю как его вставить. Это форматный ввод и вывод файла txt.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    FILE *inf /* *outf */;
    char inc[80],outc[120],b[4]="blin";
    int pr,spacecount=0,i,j,k,posn=0;
    do{
        system("cls");
        printf("Меню>\n");
        printf("1.Открыть файл\n");
        printf("2.Обработать файл\n");
        printf("3.О программе\n");
        printf("0.Выход\n");
        pr=getch();
        switch(pr)
        {
           case'1':{
           system("cls");
           inf=fopen("text.txt","r");
           if(inf==NULL)
            { printf("Не удалось открыть файл, попробуйте снова.\n"); getch(); break;}
            else
            {
           fgets(inc,80,inf);
           printf("Введенный текстовый файл:\n");
           printf("===================================\n");
           puts(inc);
           printf("===================================\n");
           fclose(inf);
            }
            getch();
           }break;
           case'2':{
            for(i=0;inc[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
              spacecount+=inc[i]==' '?1:0;
              if (spacecount==2) posn=i+2;
 
              if (posn) {
              for(j=0;j<=posn;j++) outc[j]=inc[j];
              for(j=posn,k=0;j<posn+4;j++,k++) {outc[j]=b[k];}
 
                        }
 
        }
            outc[j]='\0';
            puts(outc);
            getch();
           }break;
           }
        } while(pr!='0');
}
```

Основная обработка здесь:

```
{
      spacecount+=inc[i]==' '?1:0;
      if (spacecount==2) posn=i+2;
      if (posn) {
      for(j=0;j<=posn;j++) outc[j]=inc[j];
      for(j=posn,k=0;j<posn+4;j++,k++) {outc[j]=b[k];}
```

Comment: Жаль, что не удалось! Может напишете что Вы вообще делали в этом фрагменте кода?

Answer (score 0):

```
b[6]="blin "; // добавлен пробел для более привычного вывода. 
...
if (spacecount == 3) {  // 3-е слово - это 3-й пробел
    posn = i + 2;
}

outc[j++] = inc[i];
if (posn > 0) {
    for(k = 0; k < 5; k++) {outc[j++]=b[k];}
    // сброс счетчиков до следующих пробелов
    posn = 0;
    spacecount = 0;
}
}
outc[j]='\0';
```